# Использование метода split класса String в Java

Tags: java, строки, io, split

В данный момент изучаю по книгам Ввод-Вывод. Задача такая необходимо получить из потока ввода с клавиатуры 2-а числовых значения, которые при вводе разделяются пробелами. После чего выполнить проверку являются ли они целочисленными значениями типа int, с помощью метода parseInt конвертировать их в int и отправить эти значения дальше в программу. С проверкой вопросов не возникло. 
Ввод я решил реализовать c помощью метода readLine через InputStreamReader упакованный в BufferedReader. С этим тоже не возникло проблем.
Вопрос возник при разбиении строки на подстроки с помощью метода split() по пробелам.
Задумка была такая, что разбитая на подстроки строка записывается в строковый массив и первые два элемента этого массива передаются в созданный для проверки метод.

Когда я ввожу только одно значение без пробелов, split нечего разделять и он как я понял записывает только один элемент массива. При попытке в цикле вывести 2-а значения на экран, выдаёт ошибку выхода за границы массива. Переменную с ссылкой на этот массив я создал в самом начале.

Собственно вопрос: рассуждая логически и читая мануалы. я пришёл к выводу, что метод split() создаёт свой массив по количеству подстрок и ссылку на него записывает в ранее созданную мной переменную. Так так ли это и как можно ещё реализовать данную операцию?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main
{
    static String[] buff = new String[2];
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String edata;
        CheckInt checkInt;
        try(BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));)
        {
                edata = read.readLine();
                buff = edata.split(" ");
                for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
                {
                    System.out.println(buff[i]);
                }
        }
        catch(IOException exc)
        {
            System.out.print("Ошибка ввода вывода");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Была мысль сделать два массива. И после использования split() из одного массива в другой скопировать, а недостающие значения забить нулями. Но не хотелось плодить массивы.

Comment: Вставил твой код в идее и все заработало с первого раза

Comment: Если ввести одно значение будет вылетать исключение. Да и я больше хотел бы узнать создаёт ли split() массив под подстроки и придётся просто использовать 2-а массива или есть ещё какой то способ задать размер массива который создаёт split() если он его вообще создаёт.

Comment: Никто вам не мешает заглянуть в исходники класса String и посмотреть что возвращает данный метод. Опережая скажу, что да, сплит создает новый объект.

Answer (score 0):

У вас цикл состоит из двух итераций при i = 0 и i = 1. При массиве из одного элемента он обращается к нулевому элементу, а при обращении к первому вылетает исключение. Кто вам мешает сделать в цикле ограничение не хардкоженное (фиксированное):

```
for (int i=0, end = buff.length; i<end; i++)
```

и вводите хоть сто значений, хоть ноль.

Comment: Задумка в том, что мне нужно передать именно 2-а значения методу проверки (для отладки просто вывожу на экран) если у меня будет массив из одного элемента брать второй будет неоткуда, вылетит выход за границы массива.

Comment: То есть, если введено одно значение, вам нужно выдавать ошибку с сообщением "необходимы два значения"?

Comment: Ну да либо просто передать в метод null, я ниже написал как я решил эту задачу. Просто хотелось бы разобраться с методом split() может ли он писать в уже созданный мной массив строк, чтобы не плодить вспомогательные массивы.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main
{
    public final static int SIZE=2;
    static String[] buff;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] temp = new String[SIZE];
        String edata;
        CheckInt checkInt = new CheckInt();
        try(BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));)
        {
            System.out.print("Введите координаты: ");
            do
            {
                edata = read.readLine();
                buff = edata.split(" ");
                for (int i = 0; i < buff.length & i < temp.length; i++)
                {
                    temp[i] = buff[i];
                }
                System.out.println();
                for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
                {
                    System.out.println(checkInt.check(temp[i]));
                }
            }while(!(checkInt.check(temp[0]) & checkInt.check(temp[1])));
        }
        catch(IOException exc)
        {
            System.out.print("Ошибка ввода вывода");
        }
    }
}
```

Пока смог придумать только это, вопрос состоит в том можно ли заставить split() писать в уже существующий массив или он в любом случае создаёт свой?

Answer (score 0):

А что мешает написать??

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class tet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try {
        String edata = read.readLine();

        for(String temp : edata.split(" ")){
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

В итоге получил

```
2 5
2
5
```

Comment: for(String temps:edata.split(" "))
                {
                    if(j==2)break;
                    temp[j]=temps;
                    j++;
                }Получается что-то вроде этого

Comment: Если Вы вводите 2 числа, то Вам и выведет 2 числа. Зачем тут прописывать break на выход??

Comment: в массиве temp всего два элемента 0 и 1 если ввести большее кол-во символов, уйдёт за границы массива. Почему я сделал массив под хранение введённых чисел всего из 2-х элементов? Для того чтобы передавать эти элементы с указанием параметра длинны этого массива(temp.length). У меня основной вопрос был можно ли заставить split писать в заранее созданный мной массив без создания сплитом своего объекта. Но как я понял скорее всего нет и придётся использовать вспомогательный массив.

Comment: Я, наверное, не совсем понимаю, но если ты передаешь только 2 числа, и ты знаешь, что больше не будешь передавать, то ты не выйдешь за границы массива.
for(String temp : edata.split(" "))
Эта конструкция создаёт массив элементов String и итератор, пробегающий по элементам. Так как edata.split(" ") вернёт 2 элемента, то и итератор будет перемещаться по 2 элементам. Не пойму при чём тут выход за границы массива

Comment: Просто хотел сделать некую "защиту от дурака", чтобы даже если будет произведён ввод 1 или 3 и более значений не вываливалось в исключение при передачи этих значений методу который принимает строго 2-а значения

Comment: Теперь понятно.